Let's get critical: Aug 2014 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love Bitcoin Stack Exchange, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Final Results

Inv message structure

Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)


Restarting Vanitygen

Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)


What prevents miners in a pool from retaining the reward?

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)


Why do you need to send a transaction out with NXT to secure your address?

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 2)


How would the OpenBazaar or NXT decentralized marketplace / eBay / Craigslist work?

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)


Satoshi's final statement

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)


Does GHashIO already have above 51% hashrate?

Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)


Is there a service that let's me "send" bitcoins via email and doesn't require any account creation/login?

Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)


What is the equivalent of cold storage or paper wallet for NXT?

Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)


Is this a safe method for cold storage?

Net Score: -3 (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 3)

